# Capturing an specific logout URL in a webView to interact with an embedded html app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, html, webview

I have a simple app, with only a login page. When the user sing-in, I load a webview running an entire html5 app.

The point is that I would like to capture when the user has decided to logout.

Is there any way to listen when a specific url has been loaded?

If so, when the user press logout and the /logout.html would be loaded and I would have the opportunity of returning the control to the iOS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conform to UIWebViewDelegate in your .h file

Set your delegate of UIWebview

Implement the below method:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSLog(@"URL Request = %@",[[[webView request] URL] lastPathComponent]);
//    if (check stringlogout.html) {
//        return NO;
//    }
//    else{
//        return YES;
//    }
return YES;
}
```

Check your last component string if it is logout.html then you can do the required stuff and in else you can do what if it is not logout.html action.

Return YES if you want to load the page and return NO if you do not want to load the page.

Good luck with your app...